# Are there any DIP alternatives to the FT232R?

Tags: arduino, hardware, usb, serial

I'm currently using an Arduino on a breadboard, interfacing with it via a FT232R chip mounted on a breakout board. For my final design I'd ideally like to use all thru-hole components for ease of construction (it'll all be hand soldered) but don't really want to solder the breakout board on (though if this is the only feasible way then so be it.)

Are there any thru-hole equivalents of the FT232R chip?

Answer (score 1):

Other companies may also make this but I was able to find it on octopart.com

http://octopart.com/parts/mounting-type--through+hole/search?q=ft232r

Authorized distributors:  http://octopart.com/ub232r-ftdi-7865424